# Google API Link Rejected Key

Tags: api, key

I got an API key from Google and then submitted it with this link:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=<Google API Key>
```

Obviously, I had my actual key filled in.

The message that came back was:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
<error_message>The provided API key is expired.</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

How could the key be expired when I had just generated it?

Comment: Is it possible that you have to activate the key before you can use it?  How long ago did you create the key?

Comment: I created the key about 5 minutes before I tried to use it.  There wasn't anything on the screen that indicated that anything else needed to be done.